# Mock import failure

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

How do I make `import pkg` fail in `moduleA.py`? I can patch `pkg` to fail if something's imported from it, but not otherwise:

```py
# test.py
import os
import moduleA
from unittest.mock import patch
from importlib import reload

@patch.dict('sys.modules', pkg=os)
def test_mock():
    reload(moduleA)
```

```py
# moduleA.py
import pkg           # make this fail
from pkg import sum  # this does fail
```

[Live example](https://repl.it/@OverLordGoldDra/HummingPeachpuffPoints)

Comment: `@patch('pkg')` should do it. edit: but the patch needs to happen before you import moduleA

Comment: @jordanm `TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'pkg'`. And `moduleA` is imported within `test_mock`, then reloaded (but TypeError is raised before that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit more complicated. You have to make sure that reloading fails - this can be done by adding a class that implements [`find_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec). Second, you have to remove an already loaded package from `sys.modules` - otherwise this will be used on reload:

```py
import sys
from importlib import reload

import pytest

import moduleA


class ImportRaiser:
    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        if fullname == 'pkg':
           # we get here if the module is not loaded and not in sys.modules
            raise ImportError()


sys.meta_path.insert(0, ImportRaiser())


def test_import_error():
    if 'pkg' in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules['pkg']

    with pytest.raises(ImportError):
        reload(moduleA)
```