# How to remove a library with monkeypatch or mock in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching, pytest-mock

If my library has a `contrib` extra that has dependencies in it (say `requests`) that I want users to have to install to have access to a CLI API, but I install the contrib extra during my tests in CI how do I use [`pytest`'s `MonkeyPatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch) to remove the dependencies during tests to ensure my detection is correct?

For example, if the `contrib` extra will additionally install `requests` and so I want users to have to do

```
$ python -m pip install mylib[contrib]
```

to then be able to at the command line have a CLI API that would look like

```
$ mylib contrib myfunction
```

where `myfunction` uses the `requests` dependency

```py
# mylib/src/mylib/cli/contrib.py
import click
try:
    import requests
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    pass # should probably warn though, but this is just an example

# ...

@click.group(name="contrib")
def cli():
    """
    Contrib experimental operations.
    """

@cli.command()
@click.argument("example", default="-")
def myfunction(example):
   requests.get(example)
   # ...
```

How do I mock or monkeypatch *out* `requests` in my `pytest` tests so that I can make sure that a user would properly get a warning along with the `ModuleNotFoundError` if they just do

```
$ python -m pip install mylib
$ mylib contrib myfunction
```

? After reading some other questions on the pytest tag I still don't think I understand how to do this, so I'm asking here.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455023/mock-import-failure) answer your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51044068/2650249

Comment: Thanks both for your replies, but perhaps I should have specified that in the pytest tests I'm using the script_runner fixture from pytest-console-scripts to make sure I'm actually testing the CLI functionality. I agree that in most situations something like the [Mock import example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455023/mock-import-failure) would work, but there seems to be an issue with state of the runner I need to resolve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write unittests for an optional dependency in a python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916040/how-to-write-unittests-for-an-optional-dependency-in-a-python-package)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I ended up doing that worked, and which I had confirmed was a reasonable method [thanks to Anthony Sottile](https://youtu.be/PXu3KCMT3l4), was to mock that the extra dependency (here `requests`) does not exist by setting it to `None` in `sys.modules` and then reloading the module(s) that would require use of `requests`.
I test that there is an actual complaint that `requests` doesn't exist to be imported by using `caplog`.

Here is the test I'm currently using (with the names changed to match my toy example problem in the question above)

```py
import mylib
import sys
import logging
import pytest
from unittest import mock
from importlib import reload
from importlib import import_module

# ...

def test_missing_contrib_extra(caplog):
    with mock.patch.dict(sys.modules):
        sys.modules["requests"] = None
        if "mylib.contrib.utils" in sys.modules:
            reload(sys.modules["mylib.contrib.utils"])
        else:
            import_module("mylib.cli")

    with caplog.at_level(logging.ERROR):
        # The 2nd and 3rd lines check for an error message that mylib throws
        for line in [
            "import of requests halted; None in sys.modules",
            "Installation of the contrib extra is required to use mylib.contrib.utils.download",
            "Please install with: python -m pip install mylib[contrib]",
        ]:
            assert line in caplog.text
        caplog.clear()
```

I should note that this is actually advocated in [@Abhyudai's answer to "Test for import of optional dependencies in **init**.py with pytest: Python 3.5 /3.6 differs in behaviour"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65034142/8931942) which @hoefling linked to above (posted after I had solved this problem but before I got around to posting this).

If people are interested in seeing this in an actual library, c.f. the following two PRs:

- [`pyhf` PR #1046](https://github.com/scikit-hep/pyhf/pull/1046)
- [`pyhf` PR #1119](https://github.com/scikit-hep/pyhf/pull/1119)

A note:
Anthony Sottile has warned that

> `reload()` can be kinda iffy -- I'd be careful with it (things which have old references to the old module will live on, sometimes it can introduce new copies of singletons (doubletons? tripletons?)) -- I've tracked down many-a-test-pollution problems to `reload()`

so I'll revise this answer if I implement a safer alternative.

Comment: Maybe for clarification - but `monkeypatch.setitem` is probably better to rely on?

Comment: From this Twitter thread, Anthony would say no: https://twitter.com/codewithanthony/status/1338547566607101952 "my personal opinion is to never use the monkeypatch fixture because mocking scope is not super well defined / controlled"